# Java cannot find symbol error even though have verified classpath and .class file with javap

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm building with Maven and getting a seemingly innocuous "symbol not found" error - problem is I've verified that the build is correct with all the lower level Java tools I know and it looks airtight.  I have built with this command line:

```
javac -d /home/dan/EmailClient/Initial-Client/target/classes -classpath <many jars>:
/thepath/Common/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  /* I need this one */
-sourcepath /thepath/src/main/java: <the files> 
-s /thepath/target/generated-sources/annotations 
-g -nowarn -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8
```

Get this error:

```
Launcher.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
    return Promise.onPool(getterPool).continueWith(new Transformer<Void, Promise<List<Void>>>() {
```

(with error pointing on `onPool`)

And have run `jar xf Common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (`cd`ing by copying and pasting the directory in the command line), then

```
javap Promise.class
```

which shows

```
  public static me.unroll.functional.Promise<java.lang.Void> onPool(java.util.concurrent.Executor);
```

So this looks airtight to me - what debug step am I missing?

Furthermore this builds fine on a separate machine and runs fine from Eclipse with all relevant source files opened, just not from my actual build machine.

Comment: Silly question maybe, but is getterPool of type Executor? If it's not, then it may be complaining since it can't find an onPool that takes whatever argument type matches 'getterPool'.

Comment: @ChrisKessel Yeah, it is - rather than post more source code I just edited to note that Eclipse accepts everything as building fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to inspect the `<many jars>` section in your classpath, you are likely to find an older version of your Maven-built jar in there, which is winning the classname resolution game.

Comment: I grepped the groupId all of my code uses and found 4 jars.  I verified that the only one that contains a `Promise` class is as expected.

Comment: False; I did that on the wrong machine which was correct, this is the problem.